# Find point perpendicular to 2 points

Tags: three.js

It seems I am bad at vectors and math or forgot my entire university studies...

I have A, B, C points coordinates (X, Y, Z) where Z = 0.

[image]

C is placed in a half distance between A, B points.

[image]

D, E points are in parallel to A,B line

[image]

Any idea how to find D and E positions with three.js?

A, B, C are Vector3 three.js objects.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *C* is at half the distance between *A* and *B*, offset orthogonally, as your figure seems to indicate, then it is simple:

*D = C - 0.5AB* and

*E = C + 0.5AB*,

where *AB* is the vector from *A* to *B*.

In THREE.js, you could write it for example like this:

```
const abHalf = b.clone().sub(a).multiplyScalar(0.5);
const d = c.clone().sub(abHalf);
const e = c.clone().add(abHalf);
```

though as usual when working with vectors, there are many other ways to calculate it; you may pick your favourite approach.

Is this what you meant?